# How to start the search process in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can see the search form panel in left side, but, how can I start the search process? there is a field to put the text that I am looking for, but I don't find a button or icon to press and start the search process, I don't want to try pressing the enter button because I don't know if pressing enter will search or it will replace (since there is also a "replace" field)

[image: How to search in files in Visual Studio Code]

Regards

Comment: Enter will start the search, don't worry. If I remember correctly Ctrl+alt+enter does the replacement for all and you also have to confirm before the replacement

Comment: thanks, it works properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Enter will start the search, don't worry. If I remember correctly
>   Ctrl+alt+enter does the replacement for all and you also have to
>   confirm before the replacement – **FreshD**

thanks, I also noticed a small triangle to hide the replace field
[image]